# Equivalent DC Circuit Model of Power Converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter

This is an extract from the book 'Fundamentals of Power Electronics' - Erickson

[image]
[image]

At this point in the book, they are trying to derive the equivalent DC circuit model for a boost converter. To do so, they apply volt-second balance to the inductor waveform and charge balance to the capacitor waveform. Then, they equate each of these equations to zero.

These two equations, they say, can be used to create an equivalent DC circuit model.

I don't understand this. These equations were derived by equation two seperate periods of time together, why are they using these same equations to create a model?? If someone can just explain what they are trying to do here.

So my question really is : They are some how modelling a circuit that has two distinct phases into 1 model. They do this by equation the waveforms each of the phases to each other (or the addition of both = 0) which is the average inductor voltage or capacitor current. If the average is 0, what is this model trying to show??

Comment: Let me also add: i'm not sure I understood what exactly you were confused about. So, I wanted to answer the "Why are they doing this" kind of question.

Answer (score 3):

First, there is an assumption: that the converter is in steady-state. Assume that the capacitor has reached it's steady-state average charge, and that the inductor has an average flux. Volt-sec balance and charge balance DO NOT hold while the converter is first turning on, or if the load changes.

The goal here is to do a basic circuit analysis as simply and quickly as possible: figure out the voltages across capacitors and current through inductors. These quantities are required for figuring out the output voltages, input currents, output and input impedances, etc.

So, with that preamble out of the way. These equations were not derived at "two separate periods of time", they were derived over one complete cycle of the switching converter. This is valid because the converter is in steady state and each cycle is identical.

What they are trying to do is to provide a time-invariant view of the circuit; this lends itself to simple arithmetical (+,-,*,/) analysis. If they did not perform this simplification, you would need to integrate and differentiate your way through a switching cycle to get the output voltages, in/out currents, and in/out impedances.

The real punch would happen when you did all that work and realized your buddy next to you (who simplified it to DC terms) got the same answer and had time to drink some beers while you were still doing calculus.

Comment: Without writing my own answer that just quotes this 90% -- the charge balance and volt-second balance hold **if and only if** the converter is in steady state.  So if you _assume_ steady state, then any relationship among the various parameters that **enforces** charge and volt-second balance is one that will _result_ in steady-state operation.